What is the largest possible diameter of a shape made of centers of bounding boxes?
Given a shape in the plane (fixed in space) and an angle $\theta$, the shape's bounding box with orientation $\theta$ is the smallest rectangle containing the shape such that one of the sides is an angle of $\theta$ counterclockwise from horizontal.
We may call the center of the bounding box with orientation $\theta$, the bounding center with orientation θ, and then we may define the bounding center figure (bcf) of a shape to be the set of all bounding centers over all angles $\theta\in[0,\frac\pi2)$. (This terminology is original to me. If someone already gave this concept a name, I do not know it.)
The GIF below shows the bcf of the equilateral triangle; the result is a Reuleaux triangle, a shape of constant width. (If you're curious, the bcf of the Reuleaux triangle is a shape made of three limaçons.*) On the other hand, the bcf of any shape with twofold symmetry (such as a circle or ellipse) is a point.
There are several natural questions to ask about this concept. One natural one is: If a figure has diameter $\bf1$, what is the largest possible diameter of its bcf? (Recall that the diameter of a figure is the largest distance between two of its points.)
The equilateral triangle (shown below) gives a lower bound of $\dfrac14$. I conjecture that this is optimal. However, I am not certain how to approach proving this.


*I mentioned that $\operatorname{bcf}^2($equilateral triangle$)=\operatorname{bcf(}$Reuleaux$)$ is made of three limaçons. Up to scaling, these limaçons look like $r=\sqrt{\frac32}-\sqrt3\cos\theta$, but rotated, and shifted by $\frac{\sqrt3-1}2$. I haven't verified this algebraically, only empirically.
Most of the work towards making the GIF was done by the Discord user timpa.

Very nice question. Please [edit] it to incorporate your comments.

@EthanBolker Done.

Another natural question would be to find $\operatorname{bcf}^\infty$, that is, the limit of repeating the bcf operation. Assuming the conjecture in this question is true, repeating the bcf operation would converge to a point exponentially at a rate at least as fast as $1/4^n$. Is this point always the center of mass of the original figure, or something else?
